# Why is this bash command not echoing into a variable and what can I do to improve?

Tags: unix, bash, scripting, wget

I've got a [bash script](https://serverfault.com/questions/235501/why-does-the-time-it-takes-to-run-this-script-differ-so-much-between-user-and-sys/235529#235529) I'm working to improve, and have put on a great fix thanks to [Dennis Williamson](https://serverfault.com/users/1293/dennis-williamson). Unfortunately, one of the lines no longer echoes into a variable I can manipulate, rather dumps the output directly. I'll be good to go if I fix this.

Why is this bash command not echoing into the $result variable and what can I do to improve?

> ```
>   result=$( time wget -q --output-document=/tmp/wget.$$.html http://domain.tomonitor.com 2>&1; );
> ```

EDIT: Various solutions I've tried

```
  result=$( { time (/usr/local/bin/wget -q --output-document=/tmp/wget.$$.html --header="Host: blogs.forbes.com" http://$host) } &2>1 );

  result=$( { time (/usr/local/bin/wget -q --output-document=/tmp/wget.$$.html --header="Host: blogs.forbes.com" http://$host) } );

  result=$( ( time (/usr/local/bin/wget -q --output-document=/tmp/wget.$$.html --header="Host: blogs.forbes.com" http://$host) ) );
```

EDIT2:

I'm echoing out a line like this:

```
  echo "$date, $host, $result"
```

Date and host are currently fine. $result is not.

I'm getting lines like this:

> 3.887
>
> Tue Feb 15 08:39:53 PST 2011, 192.168.0.2,
>
> 3.910
>
> Tue Feb 15 08:39:57 PST 2011, 192.168.0.3,

I'm expecting lines like this:

> Tue Feb 15 08:39:53 PST 2011, 192.168.0.2, 3.887
>
> Tue Feb 15 08:39:57 PST 2011, 192.168.0.3, 3.910

Comment: No, look carefully at the line in my answer (and the one in my answer to your other question). (The first line in your edit is truncated, by the way.) Please be specific regarding what you want to capture and where.

Comment: Saw and fixed the truncated line. Checking on others. Thank you again for your time and patience.

Comment: You are correct. I am not sure what I missed in your answer but it is certainly the right one.

Comment: You corrected the truncated line, but I suspect that dollar sign at the end is an artifact of `nano`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need curly braces around the whole command inside the command substitution but before the redirection:

```
result=$( { time wget -q --output-document=/tmp/wget.$$.html http://domain.tomonitor.com; } 2>&1; );
```

That captures the output of `time`. If you want to capture the error output of `wget` (you're already saving its regular output to a file), you'll need to do something a little different and it depends on what exactly you want to do. It may involve extra file descriptors or simply using the redirection I showed in my answer to your other question (instead of using `--output-document`).

Comment: Thanks (again!) Dennis. I started with that per your last note but somehow lost the curly brace while trying out different solutions. For me, it doesn't yet seem to work with or without.

Comment: @editor: See my edited answer. Please let me know specifically what's happening - error messages, unexpected behavior, etc. Do you want the output of `time` in the variable? What do you want to do if `wget` outputs an error?

Comment: It works for me! Which bash version are you using? Check it with "bash --version". Is $results empty? What do you expect to get there? The output of the time command? I do get it.

Comment: Thanks for *all* the help, both Dennis and rems. I've tried to edit my answer to be more clear. The command itself is working for me, it just spits directly into the output buffer and not into a variable. The result is something that works, just not exactly as I intended. My bash version appears to be 3.2.48.

Comment: @ editor: Please be *specific*. You say it "spits directly into the output buffer". It spits *what*? The output of `time`? The output of `wget`? The error output of `wget`?

Comment: Try `var=$( { time sleep 1; } 2>&1 ); echo "[$var]"`. Is the output of `time` inside the square brackets or outside?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should go over to stack overflow but did you try this?

```
result=$( time (wget -q --output-document=/tmp/wget.$$.html http://domain.tomonitor.com 2>&1;) );
```

Comment: Just tried to no avail. I thought the command line-esque stuff came under the Serverfault umbrella but if someone needs to migrate I understand.